# TSQL Syntax for CASE WHEN in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause. A query similar to what I'm trying to write is as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Global_Sales
WHERE sales_org IN ('AM NEW ZEALAND', 'AM AUSTRALIA', 'AM MEXICO')
AND business_type IN (CASE WHEN sales_org IN ('AM MEXICO') THEN ('DIRECT SALES')
ELSE ('DIRECT SALES','INDIRECT SALES','INTERNATIONAL') END)
```

Is it possible to use CASE WHEN like this?

Understanding now I can not use CASE WHEN to return the specific result I'm after, here is a longer version I initially wrote using UNION. Since I have dozens of these, I was trying to cut down on the length and use of UNION if possible.

```
SELECT *
FROM AM_SALE_GLOBAL
WHERE sorg IN ('AM NEW ZEALAND')
AND bus_type_cd In ('DIRECT SALES','INDIRECT SALES','INTERNATIONAL','OEM') 

UNION

SELECT *
FROM AM_SALE_GLOBAL
WHERE sorg IN ('AM MEXICO')
AND bus_type_cd In ('DIRECT SALES')
```

Comment: It's generally better to use regular AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to do here?!? A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Comment: There are several countries in my sales tables. Each country has different business types in how they record sales. To find a clear picture of what the revenue is, I'm trying to say, if the sales org column is x country, pull revenue data in direct sales, if it's y country, pull indirect, and direct sales, and so on. The code provided was minimized as much as possible.

Comment: No, [from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), `CASE` returns a scalar value, not a set.

Comment: @beeehop please don't try and describe in words what you want, and especially not in a comment. [Edit] your question with sample data and desired results (as formatted text *not* images).

Comment: I can use union for this and I have done so. I'm just trying to find ways to shorted and consolidate.

Comment: So rather than asking if you can use `CASE` in this way (which you can answer yourself from the docs), ask your actual question i.e. can you simplify your already working query.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip, Dale - sorry for the misuse of the forum, I'm new and learning.

Comment: Show us your UNION query too, and perhaps we can understand what you want. (Typically you just OR the two where clauses together.)

Comment: Added a sample of the UNION version.

Comment: @AaronBertrand UNION ALL command is equal to the UNION command, except that UNION ALL selects all values and does not eliminate duplicate values. I believe either should produce the same result in this case unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: @beeehop and `UNION` is typically **much** slower than `UNION ALL`.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you both for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a `UNION`, simply `OR` the `WHERE` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM AM_SALE_GLOBAL
WHERE (sorg IN ('AM NEW ZEALAND') AND
       bus_type_cd In ('DIRECT SALES','INDIRECT SALES','INTERNATIONAL','OEM'))
   OR (sorg IN ('AM MEXICO') AND
       bus_type_cd In ('DIRECT SALES'))
```

(*Perhaps* you want `SELECT DISTINCT` - but probably not.)

Comment: Ah yes, very simple and makes so much sense. Thank you for this! I need to study up on the use of OR in this way.

Comment: Yes, some improvements are probably needed. And I'd do `sorg  = 'AM MEXICO'` instead of using `IN`

Answer (score 2):

Just use normal boolean logic

```sql
AND (
     (sales_org = 'AM MEXICO' AND business_type = 'DIRECT SALES')
  OR (sales_org <> 'AM MEXICO' AND business_type IN ('DIRECT SALES', 'INDIRECT SALES', 'INTERNATIONAL', 'OEM'))
)
```

A shorter version is

```sql
AND (business_type = 'DIRECT SALES'
   OR (sales_org <> 'AM MEXICO' AND business_type IN ('INDIRECT SALES', 'INTERNATIONAL', 'OEM'))
)
```

Another version

```sql
AND business_type IN ('DIRECT SALES' ,'INDIRECT SALES', 'INTERNATIONAL', 'OEM')
AND (NOT sales_org <> 'AM MEXICO' AND business_type IN ('INDIRECT SALES', 'INTERNATIONAL'))
```